# pandas generate new columns according to the former ones

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataset with one of the columns containing some missing values.I want to generate a new column and if the cell of the former column is missing then assign the new columns with 1,else 0.

I tried

`df[newcolumn] = map(lamba x: 1 if x is None else 0, df[formercolumn])`
but it didn't work.

While

`df[newcolunm] = df[formercolunms].isnull().apply(lambda x: 1 if x is True else 0)`

worked well.

Any better solutions to this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
df['newcolumns'] = np.where(df.formercolumns.isnull(),0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following using `numpy` which is realy similar to your solution, but slightly shorter/faster

```
df[newcolunm] = df[formercolunms].apply(lambda x: 0 if np.isnan(x) else 1)
```

I think however that Scott answer is better/faster.